# Use old ADSL modem to connect to Wifi then connect PC to modem through LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I know this question has been asked before I'm just unable to find a proper answer/guide to my question. If anyone knows of one please share.

I have an old PC that only has a LAN port(no WiFi) and an old ADSL modem router. I want to use my router to connect to my home WiFi network then connect a LAN cable from my PC to the router to gain internet access.

Comment: Short answer: not possible. A router is a sending device, not a receiving device. It cannot connect to an existing network.

Comment: Why not buy a WiFi adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're out of luck.

Ethernet routers can sometimes be flashed with alternative firmware such as OpenWRT which lets you use WiFi in client mode and achieve what you want. For ADSL routers alternative firmware is usually (always?) not available. I'm not sure why, but I suppose it has something to do with proprietary ADSL modem firmware.

Try to look for OpenWRT or other alternative firmware for this router model. If you can find it, it's probably capable of achieving your goal. The flashing procedure is risky though, you can brick the device in process.

Comment: OpenWRT pages for many ADSL modems say that the actual "ADSL modem" chip is impossible to support, due to drivers being unavailable. But since OP doesn't actually need ADSL – only Wi-Fi and Ethernet – it might still be possible to use OpenWRT for this purpose.